# Unit test of combo component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have written a compo component in angular2 and written unit test code for it.As I am a beginner so I am not able to test the component created.So please help me regarding this.

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import { ComboInterface } from './ComboInterface';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'combo-compo',
  template: `
      <select name="theme" class="form-control" [ngModel]="selectedObject" (ngModelChange)="onChangeObj($event)">
        <option [ngValue]="theme" *ngFor="let theme of dataObject" >{{theme.value}}</option>
      </select>
            `
})

export class ComboComponent {
  selectedObject: ComboInterface;
  @Input() dataObject: Array<ComboInterface>;
  @Output() onComboChange = new EventEmitter();

  onChangeObj(newObj: ComboInterface) {
    this.selectedObject = newObj;
    this.onComboChange.emit(this.selectedObject);
  }

}
```

I have written unit test code for it given below

```
describe('ComboComponent Unit Test', () => {
    let comp: ComboComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ComboComponent>;
    let de: DebugElement;
    let el: HTMLElement;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ComboComponent], // declare the test component
            imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ComboComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;

    });

    it('should create ComboComponent', () => expect(comp).toBeDefined());

    it('should create a ComboComponent with values', () => {
        comp.dataObject = [
            {
                'value': 'Victoria Cantrell test',
                'key': '0839',
            }, {
                'value': 'Pearl Crosby Test',
                'key': '8262'
            }, {
                'value': 'Colette Foley Test',
                'key': '8968'
            }
        ];
                comp.onChangeObj(comp.dataObject[0]);
    });

});
```

The code is running fine by running `npm test` but how can i test the component created ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A test uses assertions. You make assertions by using `expect`.

For instance, you expect your component to emit a value, right ?

So oyu have to put **a spy** on it : to make it easy, a spy is somethin that will **spy on your function to see if it's called**.

An example test is :

```
it('onChangeObj should emit an event', () => {
    comp.dataObject = [/* data */];
    let spy = spyOn(component.onComboChange, 'emit');
    comp.onChangeObj(/* anything you want, even null */);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

It's just a part of the test. See the auto complete of your IDE on `expect()` to see what you can do with it, you will a good idea on how to test after that !

Comment: But data is not displaying in the combo component ??

Comment: Data being shown is an end-to-end test. Here, you are unit testing. You have to test if your functions work. In the end-to-end tests, you will tests if it is displayed correctly

Comment: No I won't. I'm here to help, not to make your work. If you want tutorials, you can find [plenty of resources online](https://www.google.fr/search?q=Angular+2+e2e+testing&gws_rd=cr&ei=ZclIWZ7aEImxa-XlrZgI)

Comment: k... i will find it out through tutorials . thanks a lot for ur precious time.